# Quick Image Upload CKEditor change the language

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, javascript, image-upload

I'm using CKEditor and I want change the language of the Doksoft's plugin Quick Image Upload but it's the only one who not change.

I checked if my language is in the directory lang and in the i18n. The plugin changed with the directory lang but not with the i18n.

Can you help me please.

Thank you.